# How to only select subset of data that meets specific conditions in R?

Tags: r, parsing, subset

I'm working on parsing some data-sets (See `df` below). Every set (1-3) ideally has to have 6 rows in the column position (labelled 1-6). In my original dataset not all sets

I want only those data sets that have all the pos (1-6), and eliminate the entire set that does not have all the positions. So in this case I need to eliminate set 3. How can I do this?

```
set <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3)
pos <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5)
inf <- c(1000,200,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,500,6000,1,2,300,4000,5)

df <- data.frame(set, pos, inf)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `dplyr`, we can use `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(set) %>%  filter(all(1:6 %in% pos))

#     set   pos   inf
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1  1000
# 2     1     2   200
# 3     1     3     3
# 4     1     4     4
# 5     1     5     5
# 6     1     6     6
# 7     2     1     1
# 8     2     2     2
# 9     2     3     3
#10     2     4     4
#11     2     5   500
#12     2     6  6000
```

We can also do this in base R and `data.table` following the same logic

```
subset(df, as.logical(ave(pos, set, FUN = function(x) all(1:6 %in% x))))
```

Or

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[all(1:6 %in% pos)], set]
```

**data**

```
set <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)
pos <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5)
inf <- c(1000,200,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,500,6000,1,2,300,4000,5)
df <- data.frame(set, pos, inf)
```